# Spring XD - Singlenode as a Service

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I want to start Spring XD singlenode and leave it running. So that I can submit jobs to it using scheduler or invoke the shell anytime I want to run my modules/jobs.

How can I register Spring XD Singlenode as a Service in Linux/RHEL?

I tried starting Spring XD using 'nohup' but the nohup.out is eating the disk space.

Basically I want it to run in background like a demon / start up service.

Please advise.

Thank you.
Regards,
Kishan. G

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the process in background with :

nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1 &

This will not create nohup.out

Comment: Hi Ashish, Thanks for your reply. I will try this out and let you know the results.